# Android Design (MiniBlocks)

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, activity, design, android-view

[image: example] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]В общем, если в кратце, сделал мокинг макет приложения, которое хочу создать, но писать приложение сложнее, чем перетаскивать элементы дизайна с боковой панели на экран, поэтому задаю вопрос. Как создать вот такие миниблоки, в которых будет отображаться расписание на день.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса - как написать приложение не написав ни единой строчки кода?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что из себя представляет этот белый блок на 1 скрине, который содержит информацию о расписании.Как его оформить, в этом заключался вопрос, вот.